# Advice for troubleshooting a (url) preseed file?

Tags: software-installation, automation, preseed, troubleshooting

I'm working on my first preseed file, and to avoid having to re-burn a DVD every time I make a change, I'm hosting it on a webserver and loading it with `preseed/url=...`

To load the preseed, I'm booting a virtual machine from an edubuntu 12.04 LTS DVD, selecting the Install Edubuntu option, pressing `F6`, and replacing the `file=...` with `auto  url=...`

According to the logs on my webserver, the preseed file *is* getting downloaded by the installer, but then... as far as I can tell, it isn't being used. For example, I get prompted to select a language even though `d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US` is right there at the top of the preseed. I also tried this ["100% automated"](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization/PreseedExamples) preseed with the same results.

So, apparently something is going wrong between the installer retrieving my preseed and the contents thereof actually getting used, and I'm at a loss for how to troubleshoot this further.

If I do a `Ctrl+Alt+F2` while the installer starts, I can see a bunch of stuff happening, including several "Authentication Failed" messages that may or may not mean anything, but if that output gets saved in any way that lets me do a meaningful examination of it I haven't found it.

I'm sure I can't be the first person to have this problem, but I didn't find much when I searched for "preseed troubleshooting" here or on the Ubuntu forums, so perhaps this would be a good thread to start. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you want to see what kind of variables you have available for use in a preseed file you can view them by using nano or vi to open /var/cache/debconf/config.dat. I can't remember if this includes every option that can be applied for ever variable, but it should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution.

Short version: Live ISOs use a different installer (Ubiquity) than the one on the "alternate" ISO (d-i), which ignores many of the standard d-i preseed keywords.

I'd seen docs that recommended using the alt ISO for custom installers, but nothing explaining why, or saying what to do if you want to customize a live environment from which you can install.

I'd been thrown off by the fact that installing from a live environment undoes changes to certain config files by default, which led me to conclude that I had less control over the install than I did. It's actually pretty simple, just very, very different from a d-i install.

The best documentation I've found for this is actually not on the Internet, it's right on your system if you have the `ubiquity` package installed. Just do:

```bsh
zcat /usr/share/doc/ubiquity/README.gz | less
```

And you're off.

You can also find it online in some [source code repositories](https://github.com/linuxmint/ubiquity/blob/master/doc/README).

Comment: To add: if anyone (like me) wants a pre-seeded Ubuntu Desktop install with full control over what gets installed and how - use preseed with the minimal netinstall Ubuntu installer.

Comment: `zless /usr/share/doc/ubiquity/README.gz` should also work.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `debconf-get-selections` from the `debconf-utils` package.

After you've created a preseed file you can test with `debconf-set-selections -c preseed-file`. It won't actually exit with a failure code unless you really messed something up, but it will give warnings for incomplete answers.

From the Ubuntu example preseed:

```
### Preseeding other packages
# Depending on what software you choose to install, or if things go wrong
# during the installation process, it's possible that other questions may
# be asked. You can preseed those too, of course. To get a list of every
# possible question that could be asked during an install, do an
# installation, and then run these commands:
#   debconf-get-selections --installer > file
#   debconf-get-selections >> file
```